# Client-Authentication behind a Reverse-Proxy

Tags: python, apache, authentication, flask, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache server acting as a reverse proxy to a flask API.
The flask backend is listening on a dedicated localhost TCP port.

My flask API is sensitive, and the accessing to it must be restricted. To do so, I've configured Apache to demand client certificates. The Apache validation seems to work.

I'm currently worried about escalation of privileges. A non-root user on the machine hosting the flask API can make HTTP request directly on top of the TCP port the flask server is listening on. This effectively elevates the non-root user's privileges to root's privileges.

To summarize, the question is:

- Is there a reliable mechanism to ensure the flask server will only accept authenticated connections from the Apache proxy?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a Unix Domain socket. I've restricted the permissions on the socket to ensure it is accessible to a group that Apache and flask process belong to, but not to other process.

On my Apache configuration, I've used:

```
ProxyPass "/service_name" "unix:/etc/service_name.socket|http://localhost/"
ProxyPassReverse "/service_name" "unix:/etc/service_name.socket|http://localhost/"
```

On my gunicorn configuration (which launches the flask app), I've used:

```
bind = 'unix:/etc/service_name.socket'
group = my_service_group
umask = 0o007 # Creates files with 770 permissions, unix socket included
```